# Doesn't Ruby have isalpha?

Tags: ruby

Like Python? I'm trying to check whether each character in a string is an alphanumeric or not?

Comment: I tried googling but didn't find anything. So I just wanted to confirm with SO.

Comment: You can use regexes for this.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There's a special character class for this:

```
char.match(/^[[:alpha:]]$/)
```

That should match a single alphabetic character. It also seems to work for UTF-8.

To test a whole string:

```
string.match(/^[[:alpha:]]+$/)
```

Keep in mind this doesn't account for spaces or punctuation.

Comment: Thanks. I guess in Ruby, you have to resort to using RegEx.

Comment: You could always add a `String#isalpha?` method if you prefer that style as Sergio suggests.

Comment: I don't how this is the correct answer. [[:alpha:]] is for alphabets whereas the OP has asked for a check for alphanumeric characters.

Comment: @tourniquet_grab in that case, `[[:alnum:]]` is also an option.

Comment: don't know* how

Answer (score 20):

You can roll your own :) Replace `alnum` with `alpha` if you want to match only letters, without numbers.

```
class String
  def alpha?
    !!match(/^[[:alnum:]]+$/)
  end
end

'asdf234'.alpha? # => true
'asdf@#$'.alpha? # => false
```

Comment: Or to be more ruby-esque: `#alpha?`.

Comment: @d11wtq: absolutely. Thanks :)

Comment: `!self.match(/[^[:alnum:]]/)` is more simple.

Comment: @steenslag: that's arguable :)

Comment: In the context of a `String` instance, `self` is extraneous.

Comment: Yeah, it's a leftover from previous version of code (which you didn't see :) )

Answer (score 5):

The python function only works for ASCII chars; the [[:alnum]] regex would do things like "tëst".alpha? => true.
`match/\w/` matches underscores, so that leaves

```
def isalpha(str)
  return false if str.empty?
  !str.match(/[^A-Za-z]/)
end
```

to reproduce the Python behaviour.

Comment: python `isalpha` doesn't support string with digits

Comment: This returns `true` for empty string but should return `false`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way to do it without regex if you have trouble remembering regex (like me!):

```rb
def alpha?(char)
  char.upcase != char.downcase
end
```

For any other character than a letter, `#upcase` and `#downcase` work but have no effect, so we can assert that the char's upcase and downcase values are not equal to determine that it's a letter.

Answer (score 0):

there's an easy way to do it:

```
def isalpha(cstring) # Return true if cstring is a text
    if cstring.to_i == 0 && cstring != "0"
        lret = true
    else
        lret = false
    end
end

def isnum(cstring) # Return true if cstring is a number
    if cstring.to_i == 0 && cstring != "0"
        lret = false
    else
        lret = true
    end
end
```

Comment: you can remove the `if` in both methods since the comparison returns a boolean value.